# "Parameter" vs "Argument"

Tags: function, parameters, language-agnostic, arguments, terminology

I got *parameter* and *argument* kind of mixed up and did not really pay attention to when to use one and when to use the other.

Can you please tell me?

Comment: In Russian "parameters" are called "formal parameters", while "arguments" are called "actual parameters".

Comment: We use this convention italian as well.

Comment: I like this quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kewt1b3.aspx): "...the procedure defines a parameter, and the calling code passes an argument to that parameter. You can think of the ***p**arameter* as a ***p**arking space* and the ***a**rgument* as an ***a**utomobile*."

Comment: argument is the one you use it, while parameter is a blank to be filled in.

Comment: We pass argument(s) while calling a function and the function receives as parameter(s).

Answer (score 1239, accepted):

A parameter is the variable which is part of the method’s signature (method declaration).  An argument is an expression used when calling the method.

Consider the following code:

```cs
void Foo(int i, float f)
{
    // Do things
}

void Bar()
{
    int anInt = 1;
    Foo(anInt, 2.0);
}
```

Here `i` and `f` are the parameters, and `anInt` and `2.0` are the arguments.

Comment: Old post, but another way of saying it: `argument` is the value/variable/reference being passed in, `parameter` is the receiving variable used w/in the function/block.

Comment: Or, a method has parameters and takes arguments.

Comment: Someday I will explode and it will be a shower of developer's lingo.

Comment: Why is it that within JavaScript, when you want to access the parameters of a function/method, you have to access the "arguments" variable? Shouldn't that be "parameters" instead?

Comment: I remember it by saying "for the sake of argument, if we pass in `anInt` and `2.0`". http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+the+sake+of+argument

Comment: @ngDeveloper Nope, it should be arguments. You get access to the list of argument values passed to the function. Consequently you *don't* get a list of the parameter names of the function, javascript doesn't give you a way to get that info.

Comment: @BT You're correct that it should be arguments, but JS does give you a way to get the parameters. When you cast a function as a string, the names of parameters are in-tact if you parse them out. E.g. `function foo(a, b) {}` then `(foo+'').split(/\W+/).slice(2,-1)` produces `["a", "b"]`.

Comment: @jimbojw I stand partially corrected ; ) Neat

Comment: Citation for the above?

Comment: I feel like this is a case where the definitions should just be collapsed into 1.  There's rarely a need to differentiate between the two concepts and if you really need to just label them 'internal' or 'external' parameters or something similar.

Comment: If you like analogies- Method is like salad bowl. Argument is like greens. Parameter is like salad.

Comment: For a non-technical perspective, the general definition of parameter (beyond programming), according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/parameter) is `a set of facts which describes and puts limits on how something should happen or be done`. If you internalize this, then you'll remember that a method is bound/defined by parameters.

Comment: Brilliant! This question is torturing me for a long time! :)
Thank you so much!

Comment: Yet another way to think of this: when you have code with hard-coded values, you can make it more generic by "parameterizing" it. That is, make it into a function with "parameters" that represent any arbitrary input.

Comment: Somtimes google doc string suggestions [http://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html] has "Args" as what we formally define as "parameters" -- is it common to use "Params" instead of "Args" to document the arguments that a method receives?

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl: I see they [imported code from Copybara](https://github.com/google/styleguide/commit/cfce3c3a); in there `args` is often modelled as a iterable object; so it is not intended just in the usual meaning (aka: construct at programming-language level). Many methods in the project specify a *Parameter* called *args*, defined as an array of values (these are not defines as parameters, but they are just *runtime* values). So I think the docs author probably got confused. I would have used `settings` or `options` instead of `args`, to not confuse with the language-level arguments.

Comment: An easy way to remember: [`ARGV`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_argument_parsing) has been around since forever and has propagated from C/C++ to other languages like python, perl, ruby, js, etc, and stands for the array of values passed via the command line.