# Interface descriptions for Python

Tags: python

I have some interfaces in my Python code. I have to somehow write, what types their input parameters have and what types do the methods return.

Just now it is dome like this:

```
def megaMethod(mega_param):
    """
    A cool method! ^__^
    mega_param: ndarray
    returns: ndarray
    """
    assert False
```

What is the conventional way of such auto-documenting?

Comment: The [doxygen] tag is confusing me. If you're using doxygen, you should read the documentation for parameters. If you're not using doxygen, you should remove the tag.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334531/python-documentation-standard-for-docstring