# Python: Standard way to denote return and parameter types

Tags: python, python-2.7, types, return-type, docstring

Is there a standard, Pythonic way to express the parameter type and return type of a function?

I am looking for a notation that is:

- Recognisable by `help()`
- Recognisable by IDEs
- (Preferrably) described in a PEP

I have seen some examples, like [this reSt syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5339352/51197):

```
"""replaces template place holder with values

:param timestamp: formatted date to display
:type timestamp: str or unicode
:param priority: priority number
:type priority: str or unicode
:param priority_name: priority name
:type priority_name: str or unicode
:param message: message to display
:type message: str or unicode
:returns: formatted string
:rtype: str or unicode
"""
```

However, I am not sure how official / supported is this format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are mainly 3/4 formats competiting for the Python docstrings. See [this tuto](http://daouzli.com/blog/docstring.html) to have an overview.
The older format, now discontinued, is the **Epytext** for Epydoc based on Javadoc style. The probably more popular is the **reStructuredText (reST)** for Sphinx format. The **Google** style is also quite used. And of course the **Numpydoc** inspired from the Google style.

Concerning what should be the official/standard way you can refer to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898572/what-is-the-standard-python-docstring-format).

Each format has its own way to represent the parameters types and return type. There follows some examples:

### - Epytext / Javadoc

```
"""
@param param1: Description of param1
@type param1: type of param1

@return: description of returned value
@rtype: type of returned value
"""
```

### - reST

```
"""
:param param1: Description of param1
:type param1: type of param1

:return: description of returned value
:rtype: type of returned value
"""
```

### - Google

```
"""
Args:
  param1(int): Description of parameter `param1`.
  param2(str, optional): Description of a parameter. Defaults to None.

Returns:
  bool: True or False depending on the result.
"""
```

### - Numpydoc

```
"""
Parameters
----------
param1 : int
    Description of parameter `param1`.
param2 : {'value1', 'value2'}
    Description of a parameter with two possible values.

Returns
-------
int
    Description of the returned value
"""
```

### Converting

Note that if you have no docstrings or you want to change your docstring format for your Python project, you can use [Pyment](https://github.com/dadadel/pyment).

Comment: I use and vote for the numpydoc convention: It is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, no PEP describes this; [PEP257](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) is about docstrings, but is actually quite minimal (and stdlib docstrings are seldom as precise as yours).

The two competing standards are the one you already found, implemented in Sphinx, and the more verbose (but also much more readable) [NumPy convention](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/HOWTO_DOCUMENT.rst.txt), implemented in the [`numpydoc`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpydoc) extension to Sphinx.