# Standard comments in Python

Tags: python, comments, documentation

Is there a standar for Python comments?
I was creating a game in Python and wondering if Python has anything standard just like Java with javadocs. I really was hoping to create some kind of documentation for my game in Python but I would like it to be automatic.

Is there any standard or any simple way to achieve what I want?

Comment: While it's not a standard, many projects use https://www.sphinx-doc.org/ for source code documentation.

Comment: I'm using numpydoc which works nicely with Sphinx: https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html Example here: https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_numpy.html

Comment: https://realpython.com/documenting-python-code/

Comment: Your question is related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334531/using-javadoc-for-python-documentation.