# C++: Difference between arguments vs Parameters?

Tags: c++, parameters, arguments

Could someone explain to me the difference between an argument and a parameter?  What is passed through and what is used in the function?

Comment: Thanks for asking a question on SO! Before you ask a new question, be sure to search Stack Overflow in case someone already had the same Q! If you still can't find your answer, feel free to ask a new question. Check out this previously answered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788923/parameter-vs-argument

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, because these concepts are being asked specifically for C++.  The terminology for parameters and arguments are specified by the international standard, and they mean different things based on different language constructs.  They correlate to the C++ grammar and they make up function decelerations, definitions, call expressions, macros, templates, and catch clauses.

Answer (score 1):

You can just remember it in this simple way:

Parameter: used in definition.
Argument: used when you invoke the function.