# C++ reference in for loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, reference

As in the for loop of the following code, why do we have to use reference (`&c`) to change the values of `c`. Why can't we just use `c` in the `for` loop.
Maybe it's about the the difference between argument and parameter?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
int main()
{
    string s1("Hello");
        for (auto &c : s1)
            c = toupper(c);
            cout << s1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If not to use reference then the code will look logically something like

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < s1.size(); i++ )
{
    char c = s1[i];
    c = toupper( c );
}
```

that is each time within the loop there will be changed object `c` that gets a copy of `s1[i]`. `s1[i]` itself will not be changed.
However if you will write

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < s1.size(); i++ )
{
    char &c = s1[i];
    c = toupper( c );
}
```

then in this case as `c` is a reference to `s1[i]` when statement

```
    c = toupper( c );
```

changes `s1[i]` itself.

The same is valid for the range based for statement.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer. Really help me to understand.

Answer (score 7):

In case of:

> for (auto cCpy : s1)

cCpy is a **copy** of character on current position.

In case of:

> for (auto &cRef : s1)

cRef is a **reference** to character on current position.

It has nothing to do with arguments and parameters. They are connected to function calls (you can read about it here: ["Parameter" vs "Argument"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788923/parameter-vs-argument)).

Answer (score 1):

You can't just use `c`, because that would copy create a copy of each character, update the copy, then throw it away. References (or pointers) are the constructs C++ uses to propagate the changing of objects.