# Need assistance understanding Ruby code

Tags: ruby

I was working on a coding problem at *codewars.com*. This is the answer to said problem:

```
class Conjurer
  def self.conjure(name, lambda)
    define_method name, lambda
  end
end
```

I would like to articulate the way I am reading it, and receive criticism that helps me better understand the meaning of this code.

1. The class `Conjurer` is created.
2. An instance method of the class is called, representing the class itself.
3. It is given permanent parameters `name` and `lambda`.
4. Unsure what `define_method name, lambda` means.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253896/2988

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`define_method` makes a method named `name` and passes it a block `lambda`. So if you call the method `name`, it runs the block represented by the variable `lamba`.

The `self.conjure` is allowing you do define a method within the class: the `name` parameter becomes the name of the method, the `lambda` becomes the body of the method itself.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. The class `Conjurer` is created.

Yes. More accurately, the `Conjurer` class is opened, meaning that it's being opened for modification. In this case, the `conjure` method is being added.

In Ruby, you can open a class many times:

```
class Conjurer
  def self.something
    # code
  end
end

class Conjurer
  def self.other_thing
    # code
  end
end
```

This is the same as doing

```
class Conjurer
  def self.something
    # code
  end

  def self.other_thing
    # code
  end
end
```

> 2. An instance method of the class is called, representing the class itself.

No. It's not a method call, it's a method definition. The `def` keyword defines a new method. The `def self.` defines a method for the `Conjurer` class rather than a `Conjurer.new` instance.

> 3. It is given permanent parameters `name` and `lambda`.

Almost. The parameters are `name` and `lambda`, but they're not arguments of a call (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788923/parameter-vs-argument) for the difference between argument and parameter), because that isn't a method call, is a method definition.

> 4. Unsure what `define_method name, lambda` means.

`define_method` is part of the Ruby language. It does what is says, it defines a method with the name `name` that when called, executes `lambda`. See the docs [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method).