# why java main method parameter name is args?

Tags: java

i know method
signature use parameter,
and method use arguments when method call.

so i don't know why java main method parameter name 'args' is not 'param'

I am sorry that I am not good at English.

Comment: You are free to use any variable name as long as it is not a reserved word

Comment: yes i know that, but why Initial Name is args?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-parameter-in-main-method-java#:~:text=Those%20are%20for%20command%2Dline%20arguments%20in%20Java.&text=The%20reason%20for%20this%20is,piece%20of%20information%20it%20needs., you should better to read this posts

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Parameter" vs "Argument"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788923/parameter-vs-argument)

Comment: @samsamsamsmasma it isn't. it's just a convention they use in textbooks, it's short for arguments. But, feel free to call it fredAstaire in your code if you want. There is no "initial" or "fixed" name for that param

Comment: Convention made me understand. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just a variable name, you can use any name that meets the Java variable naming requirements

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i want know Initial Developer is use args.not a param why? is there any other meaning?

Comment: You might as well ask why the main method is called 'main'. It could have been anything.

Comment: I guess it is a historical issue. I have learned that params are used as keywords and system functions in some places.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any name for that, but "args" is short for "arguments". Some people prefer "parameter", some "argument". See also: ["Parameter" vs "Argument"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788923/parameter-vs-argument)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a matter of choice, it's about the meaning of the words: an *argument* is not a *parameter*

- `main(String args)`
  `args` is the method *argument*
- `main(null)`
  `null` is the *parameter* by which the method is invoked

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1788926/1575188