# Argument definitions in printf()

Tags: c, arguments, definition

In the following C code:

```
printf( "Coffee!" );
```

and

```
 scanf("%d", &coffee); 

 printf("\nI’m baking %d coffee!", coffee);
```

Are `"Coffee!"` and `coffee` considered arguments?

Comment: Well, they are both passed to `printf` as arguments so in that sense, yes they are arguments. Though I'm not confident that is really what you are asking. Maybe turn it around to ask what you think an argument is and is there anything in particular that makes you doubt that those are arguments?

Comment: @zackBYE344 In my point of view they are considered as drinks.

Comment: The thing that is passed to a function is an argument. `"\nI’m baking %d coffee!"` is an argument too. A *parameter* of a function is taking the value of the corresponding argument. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788923/parameter-vs-argument

Comment: As opposed to what?  What else might they be called? Possibly "parameters"?

Comment: @kaylum — your edit wasn't very good.  Yes, you indented the code, but in doing so, you left the `*` for (italic) emphasis in the text, which completely screws up the meaning in C.  I've removed those formatting stars, but that's made parts of @ryyker's answer inappropriate.  The answer critiques stuff that wasn't in the original version of the question.  I'm not sure how best to fix this.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - To be more visible, I'll repeat what I said below again here, IMO, you have already _fixed_ what confusion existed.  And from what I can guess, although asker has been quiet on the topic, I think  the question has been answered sufficiently in comments and in the answers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have provided one argument to the first call to `printf()`, and you have provided two arguments to the call to `scanf()` and two more to the second call to `printf()`.

The C standard defines both 'argument' and 'parameter':

- [§3.3 argument](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.3)
  *actual argument*
  *actual parameter* (deprecated)
  expression in the comma-separated list bounded by the parentheses in a function call expression, or a sequence of preprocessing tokens in the comma-separated list bounded by the parentheses in a function-like macro invocation.
- [§3.16 parameter](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.16)
  *formal parameter*
  *formal argument* (deprecated)
  object declared as part of a function declaration or definition that acquires a value on entry to the function, or an identifier from the comma-separated list bounded by the parentheses immediately following the macro name in a function-like macro definition.

Answer (score 2):

> *"Are "Coffee!" and coffee considered Arguments?"*

*EDITED* (in response to corrected original post by Jonathan L.)

Yes, they are both arguments.

- In the first `printf()`, *`"Coffee!"`* is a single [string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/c-string-literals?view=msvc-170) argument.
- In the second `printf()` : *`coffee`* is the 2nd argument, an `int` value.
- And finally it plays a role as the 2nd argument in the `scanf()` statement as *the location to be changed*, or in short the *address of* `coffee`  (`&coffee`)

Of course this all assumes that `coffee` was defined similar to;

```
int coffee = 0;
```

**Note** on arguments and parameters... (mentioned in comments under question)
When a function is called, the values that are passed during the call are referred to as *arguments*. The values which are used to *define the type of argument* used in a function prototype are referred to as *parameters*. ([reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-argument-and-parameter-in-c-c-with-examples/))

Comment: @kaylum misedited the question, simply indenting the code and not removing the `*` characters that were in the original, unindented code for creating (italic) emphasis.  It isn't entirely fair to the OP to critique `*coffee*` because of the misediting.  OTOH, now I've removed the inappropriate stars, it isn't entirely fair to you, either; the change invalidates part of your answer.  I'm not sure what's the best way to deal with this.  I'm open to suggestions — including rolling back my changes to the question.  (I'm not sure whether kaylum will get notified about this comment, either.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Thanks for pointing out the mis-edit in the original post. It did cause a change reaction of sorts,  but I do not think any further changes are necessary on your part. I've modified my answer in light of your new (and more accurate) edit of OP.